# Remapping: How do you remap backspace to the left side of the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

OS X here, junior level Ruby dev. I have recently remapped my Caps Lock to Escape using Keyboard Maestro and I'm loving it. I was wondering what's the "convention" or set of keystrokes for mapping Backspace to the left part of the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Keyboard Maestro, but with [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) you can for example swap the delete (aka backspace) and backtick keys:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BACKQUOTE, KeyCode::DELETE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DELETE, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Or if you for example remap caps lock to F19 with [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en), you can map pressing F19 (caps lock) to escape, holding F19 to control, and control to delete:

```
<autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::DELETE</autogen>
```

See http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html for more examples.